# Hartls Tutorial Section 3.4 rails generate controller error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following Hartl's rails tutorial and when issue the following command:

rails generate controller StaticPages home help --no-test-framework

it throws and error:

You should not use the `match` method in your router without specifying an HTTP method. (RuntimeError)
If you want to expose your action to both GET and POST, add `via: [:get, :post]` option.
If you want to expose your action to GET, use `get` in the router:
  Instead of: match "controller#action"
  Do: get "controller#action"

I am using Rails 2.1.0 and I'm wondering if that is creating the problem? Do I need to change some of the syntax in the route.rb file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be having a route in `routes.rb` for which you have not specified HTTP method.

For example: For a `PhotosController` with `show` action, use:

```
match 'photos', to: 'photos#show', via: [:get, :post]
```

I would also suggest you to use latest version of **Rails 4.x**, if you are just doing the Rails Tutorial.